# Set Paperclip image field to url without uploading

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paperclip

I have a model which takes an image called `meal`. I want to make sample data for every new account on the website, and then it will be automatically deleted after a certain number of logins.

How do I set the paperclip field `:image` in my `meal` model to store just the URL of the sample image instead of uploading a new one every time? I don't want to make a separate field in my model just for the path to the sample image, but I want to use the paperclip field `image` that I already have.

From the console I use this command to create sample data:

```
a = Meal.new(:image => File.new("#{Rails.root}/public/images/BagelCreamCheese_14.jpg", "r"), :category_of_foods => ["bagel"], :type_of_meal => "breakfast")
```

How can I simply store the URL for future sample data that will point to the same image like:

```
a = Meal.new(:image => "#{Rails.root}/public/images/BagelCreamCheese_14.jpg", :category_of_foods => ["bagel"], :type_of_meal => "breakfast")
# gives me a "No Handler Error"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably not possible, so I just ended up using the `default_url` to display a generic image for my sample data.